# android studio firebaseui version in gradle

Tags: android, database, firebase, gradle

I'm trying to sync this 
`implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui: 0.4.3'` to my `gradle` file in Android Studio; I also have this 
`implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.2.2'` in my `gradle` file as well.

I'm not sure whether I should/could use both. Anyway, the one with "auth" at the end syncs just fine. It's the first one I'm having trouble with. I'm not sure if the problem is with the version or with something else. 
Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very old version of FirebaseUI:

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui: 0.4.3'
```

You should remove it, and not depend on it anymore.

You only need the latest version of the library:

```
// FirebaseUI for Firebase Auth
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.3.1'
```

If you also need the database, add this additional dependency:

```
// FirebaseUI for Firebase Realtime Database
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.3.1'
```

Also see the [installation section in the FirebaseUI documentation](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android#installation).